# Correct Hyperledger Fabric E-Commerce Architecture

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I've only really just started looking into Hyperledger Fabric and have been asked to create an e-commerce platform (e-bay style) that uses the platform.

However, I am stuck with defining the appropriate architecture for the Hyperledger network, or if it is even appropriate to for this scenario, mainly because I do not know the number of organisations that will be part of the network at the start. Also how would this work having a single client on the front-end that users (in this case they would be organisations) would use to login, register, etc and how would this reflect on the Hyperledger network?

Would each new user be a new node on the network?

I first thought I could create a base network with just a ETCDRAFT orderer, a Fabric CA node, CouchBase, Fabric CLI node and a main Channel, and then add new organisations as they came along, but I wouldn't have anywhere to store the chain code as far I understand it.

I also thought of having the same structure but with an additional Peer node that would essentially represent the e-commerce platform itself, and new organisations (users on the ecommerce platform) would be added as users on the network, but that kind of defeats the purpose of a network in my view.

I know this might be a noob question but I am struggling a bit to define my initial set-up so that I can start writing the chain code, API and client, so any clarity on how this should ideally look in terms of network structure would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem statement is quite vague in itself.
I am trying to answer the question with my assumptions.
Let consider e-commerce website like Amazon.

How many participants in there of blockchain network?
The sellers and buyers consider them as identities of a single organization not "Node".
The peers would be the various department running in the amazon like dep1,dep2 etc.